# add on <li> active based on the url

Tags: jquery

not change this code of 'a' to 'li' in jquery
i need add in `<li>` but this code add in 'a'

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
var path = window.location.href; // because the 'href' property of the DOM element is the absolute path
//alert($('ul a').length);
$('ul a').each(function() { 
    if (this.href === path) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
    //alert(this.href);
});
}); 
</script>



<ul>
    <li><a href="Untitled-4.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.sweet-web-design.com/examples/active-item/active-class-1.html">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: do you want to assign the `active` class to the `li` instead of the anchor?

Answer (score 0):

Please replace 
 `$(this).parent('li').addClass('active');`